# TYPO3 11, ck_editor default class contenttable is missing

Tags: typo3

After updating an installation to TYPO3 11.5 I miss the default class "contenttable" in RTE frontend output. Configuration:

```
table.fixAttrib.class {
    default = contenttable
    always = 1
    list = contenttable
}
```

Nothing changed since TYPO3 10.x. But in the new version the default class is missing. I can add the class in the yaml file of the editor:

```
- { name: "Table", element: 'table', attributes: { 'class': 'contenttable' }}
```

but I need the class as default for all tables in the rte.

Is there something wrong in my installation or is there any work around?

Comment: default = contentable => you called it "contentable" instead of "contenttable"

Comment: Sorry David, it was a typo here - in TYPO3 it is correct. I fixed it in my question.

Answer (score 0):

What you configured for the RTE and the database may be superseded by the parseFunc_RTE of your Template. The effect is that
a) custom table classes appear in the ckeditor and are written to the database, but get always overwritten for output in the frontend by the parseFunc_RTE (this nearly drove me mad);
b) as I guess in your case the parseFunc_RTE HTMLparser may be disabled for some reason.

Check the Template Object Browser for the line lib.parseFunc_RTE.externalBlocks.table. There should be a configuration like in this post:
https://forge.typo3.org/issues/81676
to set class=contenttable always and only as default class

If it is missing adjust your Typoscript.setup accordingly. I hope this helps.